# Retain milliseconds in Oracle DB insert

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to insert a record in a Oracle table using Java. The field in question is defined as a timestamp.

I am using a the following statement:

```
    INSERT INTO MYTAB (UNIQUE_ID, CREATED_AT) VALUES ('137', ?)";
    PreparedStatement updatePerf = connection.prepareStatement(updateString);
    updatePerf.setTimestamp(1,getCurrentTimeStamp());
```

The getCurrentTimeStamp looks as follows:

```
    private static java.sql.Timestamp getCurrentTimeStamp() {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(time);
        System.out.println("Time in milliseconds :" + timestamp);
        return timestamp;
   }
```

When the program runs, I still the correct timestamped printed with milliseconds:

```
    Time in milliseconds :2014-05-13 15:40:03.076
```

However on the database, I only see

```
    '137',2014-05-13 15:40:03
```

I want to retain the milliseconds desperately.

Comment: Is the type a `TIMESTAMP` or a `TIMESTAMP(0)`?

Comment: How is the MYTAB table defined, do you have a create table you can post?

Comment: What type is `MYTAB.CREATED_AT`? If it's just an Oracle `Date`, you can only get down to `second` precision.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "on the database, I only see", how are you getting the data out of Oracle?  Have you proerly set NLS_TIMESTAMP?
Try setting:

```
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF'
```

in `SQL*Plus`, and then try the query, and see if you can see thw milliseconds component.

Alternately, you can format the timestamp column w/ a `to_char()` function:

```
select to_char(my_timestamp_col,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF') from my_table;
```

Note also, that if your column is timestamp with timezone, you'll need to set `NLS_TIMETAMP_TZ_FORMAT` instead.